# Tapestry 5 Create binding for parameter in child class

Tags: tapestry

I created component BannerUpload which extends core Upload component. I have property UploadedFile inside this component. But I don't see any way to pass it to the **value** parameter of parent class. I've tried to define method **UploadedFile defaultValue()** but it didn't help as it's meant for container...

```
public class BannerUpload extends Upload {
    @Property
    private UploadedFile bannerUpload;

    public void doUpload() {
        // ... upload file ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a mixin and @BindParameter instead of extending the upload component. If you set a field marked with @BindParameter, this will be pushed through to the component. I'm not sure if this annotation also works in subclasses?

eg

```
<t:upload t:mixins="mymixin" />

public class MyMixin {
    @BindParameter
    private UploadedFile value;

    @SetupRender
    void initializeValue() {
        // set value here
    }
}
```

http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/annotations/BindParameter.html